# Controlling spinning carousel (3D) in AS3 -- how to get it to spin to specific element?

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, carousel

I'm building a 3D spinning carousel in AS3, basing it on Keith Peter's example.

I've got the carousel up and spinning and all is well, so far, but I can't for the life of me determine how to *control* it so that it spins to a specific element.  I know it's just math, but right now, under tight deadline, I'm not grokking it.  Any help appreciated.

I set it up with code below — there are currently 10 elements so each is spaced 36 degrees from the rest -- but ultimately there may be more or less elements, so it needs to work with a variable number.  I want, for instance, to say 'spin to element 4' and it will spin there.

Thus I'm looking to set _container.rotationY, based on the specific element to which I want to go.  So (pseudocode)

```
function gotoElement($element:int):void {

    _container.rotationY = ?

}
```

I also need to figure out how to keep _container.rotationY between 0 and 360, but I suppose that's a simple modulus?

Any help GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks!

```
private function createCarousel():void
    {

        _container.z = 0;
        addChild(_container);

        for (var i:int = 0; i<_numberOfImages; i++) {
            var angle:Number = Math.PI * 2/_numberOfImages*i;
            var item:JukeBoxAlbum = _images[i];
            item.x = Math.cos(angle) * RADIUS;
            item.z = Math.sin(angle) * RADIUS;
            item.rotationY =  (-360/_numberOfImages)*i + 270;
            _items.push(item)
        }                    

        sortItems();
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop,false,0,true);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click,false,0,true);


    }
```

Comment: how do you currently rotate to the correct item?

Comment: i think the best bet would be to create an array with the elements and use that to navigate to the correct item in the carousel.